# Eclipse Neon php XDebug form action=post in WordPress

Tags: php, eclipse, wordpress, xdebug

Objective: debug a php script triggered from an HTML form with action=POST from within a WordPress Page.

What works: I can initiate a debugging session for index.php. This results in the web page displaying in the browser view. I can then click on any links on the page, which in turn triggers a new call to index.php. I can step through the WordPress code with no problems, set breakpoints and so on.

The apache server is on my workstation, localhost, running Ubuntu Linux.

In one page there is a form. When I click the submit button, I get a message in the browser view saying:

```
Unable to load page
Problem occurred while loading the URL file:///xyz.php
Error opening file: No such file or directory
```

It seemed to me that Eclipse is looking for the php file at the workstation root directory instead of the server root. So I put a symbolic link at the root level to the php script to see if Eclipse would find it.

Now when I click on the link I get a File Dialogue asking me do I want to download the php script.

It seems there must be a wrong setting somewhere but I am at a loss. As it stands I can only debug code that is triggered by a GET, not a POST.

If I run the script in Eclipse without debugging, I can post the data and the post script executes. It is only with the debugger that I get the file not found error, so it seems to be in the debugging config:

```
Server Name: Nip.yt
Base URL: http://nip.yt (127.0.0.1 - works fine in browser)
Document Root: /home/peter/Documents/localhost/html/nip
Path Mapping
Path on Server: /home/peter/Documents/localhost/html/nip
Path in Workspace: /nip
```

I have tried replacing Path on Server with / with identical results.

Any and all advice appreciated.

EDIT:

I am now using php5.6 with Zend Debugger, but exactly the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Hanging his head rather sheepishly, he says...

I solved the problem. I just put the full URL in the

Doh...

Why didn't I think of that sooner???